# Writing to and then modifying CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am running a webscraper that saves train information into a text file. This information is constantly updated, so I am accessing this page once every minute (and saving all information immediately).

Each train has a destination (city name), a due date, and a delay (0 for on time, -x for early by x minutes and x for late by x minutes).

The delays can update from minute to minute, and when this happens, I need to go back and edit the row in my file, that corresponds to the train where the change happened. The main thing I am concerned about, is that regardless of the format I am storing my files in, I am not sure how to go back and identify the correct row easily (and to find the correct one, even if there are possible duplicates), because none of this information is unique to identify a row. I have thought of the following solutions:

1. Adding a row number (or id, whatever) to each of these, and storing them in an internal buffer in python, then identify the row by this number.
2. Create a unique id by some algorithm using the time and location and use that to ID the column.
3. Use a database (urgh)

Which one do you think would be the best, and what format should I go with that allows this the best? I was thinking .csv, but unless there is a parser that can do something along the lines of "load file -> find ith record -> set column[x] to something -> save file", I am not sure if there is any point.

Comment: Have you a code?

Comment: I have the code built for scraping the web, but I haven't started the file writing part yet because even after research I am not too sure what direction to go yet, hence the question

Comment: I'd recommend a database in this situation, it will be more reliable and probably faster than using a file as a makeshift db.
If you do end up going the csv route: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Unless the format is fixed width data, you can't easily just modify a value in the file, you need to rewrite the whole file. As you're using csv, this isn't fixed width.

Comment: how many records and columns are??

Comment: @PeterWood this is my other issue, the fact that I would have to rewrite the entire thing :(

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar 5 columns and a dynamic number of rows (the amount of trains that pass changes constantly) (not exceeding 1000)

Comment: then the name trains is the KEY ? right ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar my problem is exactly that; there is no information about any train that can uniquely identify it, and even a combination of time and destination (or origin) could result in duplicate entries being flagged as candidates

Comment: then you can only insert .... I don't think it is possible to update if there is no like a primary that we can use ....another thing is you can insert all ....and on your final process make a select distinct NameTrain with max values like date arrive ..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite would be a good fit.  It is a simple file-based storage mechanism (like CSV), but you can use SQL commands to modify specific values without having to re-write the whole file.

https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Comment: Love SQLite for projects like these. OP, I think for a project like yours, constantly saving into a CSV file will cause lots of extra code not needed that a database can do on its own really well. If you are interested in using it but are worried about a hard setup, I would highly recommend using [Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) to manage the database in a very easy way.

Comment: @Lewis thats mostly what I was worried about tbh - I couldnt really find libraries that I liked, that seemed easy enough. I have a background in websites so I am fully aware of the capabilities of databases but thought it would be easier to not go that way - seems it will be the direction i am taking, thanks guys!